# Recently run queries WITH parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the recently run queries on SQL Server. I can currently do this by running the query below, however this does NOT show me the parameter values.

Is there any way to get this as well?

```
SELECT 
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs  
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY 
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Thanks
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately, you'd have to use Profiler for that

Comment: So does the profiler show recently executed queries with parameter values? Any pointers on how to start this up. I believe I have profiler.

Comment: @user554134: No, it traces calls in real time only. It doesn't read the dmvs (aka recent calls from cache)

Answer (score 2):

Parameter values are saved in cached execution plan.
run following query

```
SELECT execsql.text AS [Script], 
   q.query_plan,
   execquery.last_execution_time       
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(execquery.plan_handle) q
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
WHERE q.dbid = db_id('dbname') and last_execution_time > 'datetime' 
AND execsql.text LIKE '%any filter like table name%' 
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC;
```

Copy xml from query_plan column and see ParameterCompiledValue node. You will find compiled parameter values here.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the last query with parameters for the specific session as the flowing:

```
select 1 as anything;
SELECT text
FROM sys.[dm_exec_connections] SDEC 
CROSS APPLY sys.[dm_exec_sql_text](SDEC.[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS DEST 
WHERE SDEC.[most_recent_session_id] = @@spid
order by connect_time desc;
```

@@spid will get the current execution session.

Comment: that query does not give the parameter values.