# Parameters pass to a query in azure sql server database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a web app the run queries with parameters on sql server azure .

While i can see in the database that the query were pass to the database i cant see which parameter were pass and all i can see is @P1.

Is there any way to see what are the parameters in SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio )?

I am using this script to observe it:

```
SELECT query_stats.query_hash AS "Query Hash", 
SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / 
SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS "Avg CPU Time", 
MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS "Statement Text" 
FROM (SELECT QS.*, 
SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1, 
((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text) 
ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) 
AS statement_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS 
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats 
GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash
```

Comment: where do you "see" this and what do you "see"? What tool are you using to see it?

Comment: I am using SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio )

Comment: You won't see anything in SSMS unless you run some kind of script. What script are you running to actually see `@P1`?

Comment: SELECT query_stats.query_hash AS "Query Hash",    SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS "Avg CPU Time",
MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS "Statement Text"
FROM
    (SELECT QS.*,
    SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END
        - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
   FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash

Comment: This question says it can't be done, you have to use SQL Profiler (it's on the SSMS menu - does that count?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193553/recently-run-queries-with-parameter-values